# How to plot density of lines with plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Let's say I have a set lines (y vs. x) that are the result of a random process.

I am looking for a visualization that shows the spread of the lines.

Concretely I am looking to get an e.g. transparency-graded filled region where the opacity corresponds to the height of the histogram at that point.

Somewhat like the [plotly "Filled Lines" example](https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/#filled-lines), except that I am not looking for hard borders to the area filled but a gradual phasing out using transparency.

One example similar to what I am looking to realize is shown in on [this blog](http://blog.enthought.com/general/visualizing-uncertainty/):
[image]

I would like to plot different sets of lines (e.g. different experimental conditons) on the same plot in different colours to visually compare their results.

Comment: The answer from dubbbdan is fantastic. Since you've tagged your question with plotly, would you consier marking my contribution as the accepted answer? Or maybe you've found an even better approach by yourself by now?

Comment: @vestland Thanks for the reminder. I did end up using a self-rolled alternative but only because I wanted to normalize the intensity over the `x` value. That requirement was not in the question though.

Comment: Sounds cool! Did you use plotly? In that case, would you consider sharing your approach? You *could* write it up as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're specifically asking for `Plotly`, one approach could be to visually represent all your results from your random process with an indiviudal line and a certain opacity.

**Plot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
# imports
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# random data
np.random.seed(123)
frame_rows = 50
frame_cols = 500
frame_columns = ['V_'+str(e) for e in list(range(frame_cols+1))]
df=pd.DataFrame()

for col in frame_columns:
    df[col]=np.sin(np.arange(0,frame_rows/10, 0.1)*np.random.uniform(low=0.85, high=0.99))

# plotly figure
fig=go.Figure()
for i in range(1, frame_cols):
        #print(str(i))
        fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index,
                                 y=df[df.columns[i]].values,
                                 showlegend=False,           # hides trace name from legend
                                 hoverinfo='skip',           # turns off hoverinfo
                                 name = None,
                                 mode = 'lines',
                                 line_color='black',
                                 opacity = 0.008
                                )
                     )

# add mean of all rows to the plot
df_mean=df.mean(axis=1).to_frame()
df_mean.columns=['mean']
# show mean
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_mean.index, y=df_mean['mean'].values,
                          name='mean lines',
                          line_color='red',
                          line=dict(width=2),
                          mode='lines')
             )
        
fig.show()
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Thank you.

Comment: @ARF Interesting question. Happy to help!

Comment: One problem I had with your approach, which still looks very cool, was that I found no way of removing them from the legend and from capturing the "inspect trace" cursor. It makes both tools practically useless. Ideally I would only have liked my "mean line" to appear in the legend and be inspectable with the cursor.

Comment: @ARF I changed my answer to hopefully get what you wanted in the end. We just needed to include `hoverinfo='skip'` and `showlegend=False` in the existing `go.Scatter()`, and then add a trace line with row averages without those limitations.

Answer (score 1):

One approach you could use is matplotlib's [`LineCollection`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/shapes_and_collections/line_collection.html).  You can use `cmap` and explicitly assign alpha transparency to each line int the collection.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection


N = 100
x = np.arange(N)
# Here are many sets of y to plot vs x
ys = [x**2+ x + i for i in x]

# We need to set the plot limits, they will not autoscale
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_xlim(0,20)
ax.set_ylim(0,200)

verts = [np.column_stack([x, y]) for y in ys]

a_first = np.linspace(0,1,50)
alpha_array =np.concatenate((np.flip(a_first),a_first))

line_segments = LineCollection(verts,linewidth=2, cmap="Blues_r", array=alpha_array)
ax.add_collection(line_segments)
fig.colorbar(line_segments)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Though not exactly what I was looking for. Here the transparency is associated with a specific line. A given line may however lie in the centre of the distribution (dark) for some values of x and in the tails of the distribution (light) for other values of x.

Comment: @ARF Since you didn't provide any data to work with, that is the example I worked up using the matplotlib docs examples.  If had the distribution data, it would be pretty simple to scale the transparency to be darker in the middle and lighter the farther you get away from the center.    I used `np.random.uniform`, which gave a random pattern.  If you provide some data, I am happy to update the answer.

Comment: @ARF Updated answer to scale the alpha transparency to be darker in the middle and lighter the farther you get away from the center.